# First derivative of fitted GAM changes according to specified model distribution

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have built two GAMs, one with `family = gaussian` specification and one with `family = Gamma(link = "log")` specification.

```
gam.gaussian <- gam(weight_t ~ 
             tagged + 
             sex_t0 +
             s(age.x, k = 6) + 
             s(scale_id, bs = "re") + 
             s(age.x, scale_id, bs = "re"), 
           data = long, 
           method = "REML")

gam.gamma <- gam(weight_t ~ 
             tagged + 
             sex_t0 +
             s(age.x, k = 6) + 
             s(scale_id, bs = "re") + 
             s(age.x, scale_id, bs = "re"), 
           data = long, 
           method = "REML", 
           family = Gamma(link = "log"))
```

Both models produce very similar predictions (below), which show that body mass increases non-linearly with age. The depicted/predicted relationship is however not hugely non-linear.

[image]

I would now like to get the first derivative of this curve using finite differences to look at how growth changes with age. For `gam.gaussian` this is easily done:

```
fd <- derivatives(gam.gaussian, newdata = pred.dat2,  term = "s(age.x)")

f7 <- ggplot(fd, aes(x = data, y = derivative)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.2) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2, colour = NA) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  xlab("Age (days)") + 
  ylab("BM % daily growth (g)"); f7
```

[image]

However, using the same code for `gam.gamma` produces a completely different plot.

[image]

I could not find any info to say exactly what is being plotted, however I suspect that it is specific growth rate (SGR):

SGR = [log(size_t+1) - log(size_t)] / [time_t+1 - time_t]

I assume that SGR is plotted because by specifying a non-gaussian distribution I am essentially saying that body mass does not increase linearly with age? ....maybe?

Both graphs essentially show the same thing - growth rapidly increases early in life and plateaus later in life. However, as the relationship between body mass and age is not hugely non-linear, and the first growth figure is easier and more intuitive to interpret, I am keen to calculate the first derivative from `gam.gamma` by the same method used for `gam.gaussian`.

My two questions are:

1. Why does changing the model distribution change the method by which the derivatives are calculated?
2. How would I calculate derivatives from `gam.gamma` using the same method as what is used for `gam.gaussian` so that I can produce the same figure (the first growth figure)? Is this an appropriate/reasonable thing to do (given that the relationship between body mass and age is not hugely non-linear and the first growth figure is easier and more intuative to interpret)?

Comment: This is apparently a question about an R function called `derivatives` but you don't tell us where you got this function from or what it is documented to do. There is no function by that name in the core R packages or in the gam package or in the mgcv package.

Comment: @GordonSmyth It's from my *gratia* package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `derivatives()` function was intended for computing derivatives *for single smooths* on the *scale of the link function*.

For the Gaussian GAM, the link and response scales are the same thing as the link function is the identity function. For the gamma GAM, the link and response scales are different; the derivatives are computed on the log scale here as you used a log link. We do *not* backtransform those derivatives to the response scale.

The best plot to visualise what you are getting derivatives for is that shown by `draw()`, which shows the smooths on the link scale (just like `plot.gam()` does), not model predictions as `derivatives()` doesn't yet work for model predictions, only single smooths.

If you compare the plots for the smooth of interest produced by `draw()` for your two models, you should see why the derivatives look quite different.

If you want derivatives of model predictions, you'll need to either do the finite differences yourself using model predictions for the covariate values you want, or wait until I find some time to add this as an option to *gratia*. If you go with the faster solution (do it yourself) you can use the functionality I wrote to support `derivatives()`, but much of it is not exported so preface functions with `gratia:::` or just copy the code into your own functions (respecting the licence if you ever distribute your code).

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the total derivative of a variable used in interaction(s)?


Example:
`quantity ~ age + s(price) + s(price, by=age)`


The reason I'm asking is that this would be useful for demand elasticity modelling, where elasticity is defined as:
`d(quantity) /  d(price) * price / quantity`


Note: quantity would be the predicted quantity, and price would be the observed price.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson how would you calculate derivatives of smoothers and the corresponding CIs on the response scale?

Comment: @statmerkur The easiest way would be to create two new data frames; one with the values of the covariate you want derivatives for and a second with those values shifted a little. Then a forward difference (the finite difference one usually thinks of). Call these `fit_original` & `fit_forward` respectively and `eps` is the amount you shifted the original values. The first forward finite difference is then: `(fit_forward - fit_original) / eps`. Getting an uncertainty interval is more involved, requiring some math that I'm not familiar with or using posterior simulation.

Comment: ... so repeat the above steps for a large number of draws from the posterior of the model. This is a little trickier to do as it requires knowledge of some of {mgcv}'s lower-level functions. This is pretty close to the top of my TODO list for {gratia} so it might be implemented in the next couple of weeks. If you can't wait, perhaps ask your question as its own question on this site and I'll write some rough code to show how it would be done.