# Confidence intervals for derivatives from GAM predictions

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have built the following GAM model in `mgcv`

```
wt9 <- gam(weight_t ~ 
             tagged + 
             sex_t0 +
             s(age.x, by = tagged, k = 5) +
             s(age.x, by = sex_t0, k = 5) + 
             s(scale_id, bs = "re") + 
             s(age.x, scale_id, bs = "re"), 
           data = long, 
           method = "REML")
```

I then made population averaged predictions from this model.

```
# Create new data frame to predict from
pred.dat <- data.frame(tagged = c(rep(0, 752), rep(1, 752)), 
                       sex_t0 = c(rep("f", 376), rep("m", 376), rep("f", 376), rep("m", 376)),
                       age.x = c(rep(seq(9, 384, 1), 4)),
                       scale_id = rep(1, 1504))

# Define factors in new data frame
pred.dat$tagged <- factor(pred.dat$tagged)
pred.dat$sex_t0 <- factor(pred.dat$sex_t0)
pred.dat$scale_id <- factor(pred.dat$scale_id)

# Population averaged predictions from fitted gam wt9
preds <- predict(wt9, 
                 newdata = pred.dat, 
                 exclude = c("s(scale_id)", 
                             "s(age.x,scale_id)"), 
                 se = T)

# Combine predictions to new data frame for plotting
pred.dat <- cbind(pred.dat, fit = preds$fit)
pred.dat <- cbind(pred.dat, se.fit = preds$se.fit)

# Calculate 95% CI for predictions from predicted standard errors
pred.dat$lci <- pred.dat$fit - (1.96*pred.dat$se.fit)
pred.dat$uci <- pred.dat$fit + (1.96*pred.dat$se.fit)

# Plot predicted weight for tagged and untagged, and male and female, animals through time (+/- 95% CI)
mycolours1 <- brewer.pal(4, "Blues")[3:4]
mycolours2 <- brewer.pal(4, "Greens")[3:4]

f2a.1 <- ggplot(pred.dat, aes(x = age.x, y = fit, colour = tagged:sex_t0, fill = tagged:sex_t0)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lci, ymax = uci), alpha = 0.2, colour = NA) + 
  scale_colour_manual(labels = c("Untagged female", "Untagged male", "Tagged female", "Tagged male"), values = c(mycolours1, mycolours2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Untagged female", "Untagged male", "Tagged female", "Tagged male"), values = c(mycolours1, mycolours2)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12), legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  xlab("Age (days)") + 
  ylab("Body mass (g)"); f2a.1
```

[image: Predictions from fitted GAM]

I would now like to create an equivalent figure for the first derivatives of these curves.
I can create and plot the derivatives manually but am struggling to get confidence intervals. I have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207250/determining-derivatives-from-gam-smooth-object) to obtain the first derivatives manually.

I understand that there is no function to automatically calculate first derivatives and confidence intervals from model predictions. The `derivatives()` function from the `gratia` package will calculate first derivatives and confidence intervals from a fitted GAM but not from model predictions, see answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495775/first-derivative-of-fitted-gam-changes-according-to-specified-model-distribution).

```
eps <- 1e-7
X0 <- predict(wt9, 
              newdata = pred.dat, 
              exclude = c("s(scale_id)", 
                          "s(age.x,scale_id)"), 
              se = T, 
              type = 'lpmatrix')

pred.datFeps_p <- pred.dat
pred.datFeps_p$age.x <- pred.datFeps_p$age.x + eps

X1 <- predict(wt9, 
              newdata = pred.datFeps_p, 
              exclude = c("s(scale_id)", 
                          "s(age.x,scale_id)"), 
              se = T, 
              type = 'lpmatrix')

# finite difference approximation of first derivative
# the design matrix
Xp <- (X1 - X0) / eps

# first derivative
fd_d1 <- Xp %*% coef(wt9)

test <- cbind(pred.dat, fd_d1)

ggplot(test, aes(x = age.x, y = fd_d1, colour = tagged:sex_t0, fill = tagged:sex_t0)) + 
geom_line(size = 1.2) + 
scale_colour_manual(labels = c("Untagged female", "Untagged male", "Tagged female", "Tagged male"), values = c(mycolours1, mycolours2))
```

[image: First derivatives plot]

**Q: How can I obtain confidence intervals for these first derivative curves? Noting that these are model predictions and not plotted directly from the fitted GAM.**

Answer (score 2):

You can do posterior simulation to draw a large set of samples from the posterior distribution of the model, and then for each sample (which is one set of curves if you are predicting for all your groups over a grid of values in `age.x`) compute the derivatives and store the values.

This gives you a posterior distribution for the derivative of each curve for each value of `age.x`. You can then summarise those posterior distributions using some suitable quantiles (0.025 and 0.975 probability quantiles say for a 95% interval) to directly estimate the confidence interval on the derivative.

This is all assuming a Gaussian approximation to the posterior, which works OK a lot of the time but can fail in some others. Simon Wood has implemented INLA and a simple Metropolis Hastings sampler to also generate samples from the posterior distribution of the model, which shouldn't have the same problems that Gaussian approximation has in some situations.

If you want to simplify the process (currently only for Gaussian approximation) you can use `fitted_samples()` from **gratia** to get the posterior draws for the input data you specify. Then you can compute the derivatives from those posterior draws, etc.